# Persistent connection to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, freepascal

I have a database on a local machine that is queried repeatedly as fast as possible.
Currently I am executing `mysql_real_connect()` before each query and `mysql_close()` right after. Since speed is of the essence, connecting and reconnecting creates an unacceptable amount of overhead.

I have done some research and found a `mysqli` command to create a persistent connection (`mysqli_pconnect`). Unfortunately I am not using PHP (I am using the `mysql50` library in `FreePascal`/`Lazarus`) and the `mysqli` library is not available to me; I have to settle for the standard `mysql_*` commands.

Does anyone have a solution?